# PyQt5のボタンで押した時間分だけ入力される方法

Tags: python3

pyqt5のpressedを使い、押した時間分だけ命令が実行される方法を探しております。

どうか、ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

QAbstractButtonクラス（QPushButtonクラスのスーパークラス）のsetAutoRepeatメソッドにTrueを指定することで、ボタンを押しっぱなしにした際にpressed, released, clickedシグナルが一定間隔で発生するようになります。
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop

setAutoRepeatDelayメソッドで押しっぱなしと判断するまでの時間を、autoRepeatIntervalメソッドで発生させるシグナルの間隔を指定します。両方とも、引数はミリ秒で指定します。

コード例を示します。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.counter = 0

    def initUI(self):
        btn2 = QPushButton("Button", self)
        btn2.move(50, 50)
        btn2.setAutoRepeat(True)
        btn2.setAutoRepeatDelay(1000)  # 1秒
        btn2.setAutoRepeatInterval(300)  # 300ミリ秒

        btn2.pressed.connect(self.updateStatusBar)

        self.statusBar()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 150)
        self.show()


    def updateStatusBar(self):
        self.counter += 1
        msg = self.sender().text() + ' was pressed... {}'.format(self.counter)
        self.statusBar().showMessage(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

画面に表示されるButtonを1秒以上押しっぱなしにすると、ステータスバーのテキストの末尾の数値が300ミリ秒ごとにインクリメントされることが確認できると思います。